# Pick random lines from file with fixed seed (pseudo-random)

Tags: perl, random

I would like to randomly pick some lines (e.g.20) from a file and print it into another but I want to have a seed fixed so that I get the same output if input file is the same.

The examples I've found that pick several lines, their output is different everytime 
e.g:

```
perl -e '$f="inputfile";$_=`wc -l $f`;@l=split( );$r=int rand(@l[0]);system("head -n$r $f|tail -20")'> outputfile
```

And those that talk about fixed seed and pseudo-random are just for printing numbers, not extracting lines from files, or just extract a single line. Is there a command for unix or some code in perl or similar? (`sort -R`, `--random-` & `shuf` didn't work (using Mac OS X 10.5.8)).

Comment: I found a solution using `rand()` in perl and previously setting the seed `srand(<some_nmber>);` (for ex. srand(5)). My question is... is there any rule when choosing the seed, such as... "the seed shouldn't (or should) be bigger than the total number of lines..? Thank you very much

Comment: The answer should be complete in itself and not refer to a comment. I've edited it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the seed via srand(); (for example. srand(5)) to get a fixed seed for rand.